# Использование алгоритма разбиения

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Задано множество X = {x1, x2, …, xn} целых положительных чисел и
число S. Требуется узнать, может ли число S быть представлено как сумма
некоторых из чисел множества X, если каждое число можно использовать не
более чем по одному разу. Только изучаю алгоритмы, и вот такое задание попалось, единственное что я понял, нужно работать с алгоритмом разбиения. Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: читаем комбинаторику. реализуем классическую задачу получения сочетаний без повторений, попутно узнавая что такое рекурсия. Радуемся полученным знаниям

Comment: Если вы научились решать задачу для девяти чисел, то как вы решите её для десяти? Можно из первого решения составить второе?

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev радуемся асимптотики 2^n, прекрасная новость

Comment: @Neuro, перебирать все комбинации не нужно. Для некоторых множеств и сумм перебор может быть значительно сужен.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy в ответах написано два наилучших способ решения этой проблемы, к сожалению перебор с эвристиками, может работать быстро, но он все еще очень медленный

Answer (score 1):

Это классическая задача на темы Meet in the Middlе, идея состоит в том, чтобы разбить данное множества на два подмножества примерно одинакового размера, и посчитать суммы представленные для каждого подмножества, стоит заметить что асимптотика такого метода намного быстрее обычного перебора, так как обычный перебор занимает 2^n(нам надо перебрать все подмножества), тогда как Meet in the Middle позволяет добиться асимптотики в sqrt(2^n), или 2^(n/2), что намного быстрее изначальной асимптотики, так как разумные ограничения первой это - n=20, а для второй n = 40. Подробнее об этом методе можно прочитать [здесь](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/meet-in-the-middle/#:%7E:text=Meet%20in%20the%20middle%20is,individually%20and%20then%20merge%20them.), там практически такая же задача, с правильной реализацией. Такая же задача как у вас представлена на [CSES](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1628), если вдруг нужно будет проверить реализацию.

[А вот и написанная реализация](https://cses.fi/paste/8da5925caa14ba0830529b/)

Comment: А если чисел сотни, а S не так уж велико, что можно ещё сделать?

Comment: Если чисел сотни, то больше куба вы ничего не сможет сделать: осталось перебрать числа, пары чисел и тройки чисел, и уповать на то что этой зайдет, это для S<=max_3({X})

Answer (score 0):

Если данные такие, что `S` не слишком велико, то можно воспользоваться динамическим программированием. Метод работает за `O(S*length(X))`

Сумму `i` можно составить из текущего значения `x` и уже имеющейся (если она есть) суммы `A[i-x]`. Цикл в обратном порядке позволяет избежать неоднократного использования элемента в сумме.

```
int X[] = {2,7,13,17,23,31};
int S = 40;
std::vector<int> A(S + 1);

A[0] = 1;
for (int x : X) {
    for (int i = S; i >= x; i--) {
        if (A[i - x])
            A[i] = 1;
    }
}
if (A[S])
    std::cout << S << " sum possible";
```

Comment: Работает за другую асимптотику, а именно это NP - полная задача, полиномиальною решения нет

Comment: Если же вы говорите о номинальном представление суммы, схожее с задачами о монетах, то похоже автору нужно другое `нужно работать с алгоритмом разбиения`

Comment: @Neuro Это псевдополиномиальный алгоритм, как указано - зависит от значения суммы. `автору нужно другое` автор не знает, что ему нужно для решения задачи. Для малых n и больших S подойдёт Meet in the Middlе, для наоборот - ДП,